# Identifying a version of Cards Against Humanity

Tags: cards-against-humanity

I have an unopened box of Cards Against Humanity that I was gifted a few years ago. I would like to sell it.

As there are different versions, I would need to be able to say which it is. How can I find out without removing the plastic wrapping?

Comment: You should post a picture of what you have otherwise we can't help.

Comment: I was hoping this question could be more generically useful, with answers like "look here for the version number". If they're just an arcane system where you need the individual box and an almanac (wouldn't put it past them), fair enough- I'll post when I get the chance.

Comment: Your question is about identifying your version and not identifying a version in general. If you want a generic answer you should edit your question to say that.

Comment: Wait, just to clarify. If I were to ask "How can I tell which set this Magic: The Gathering card is from", you would need a picture of the card to be able to answer "the set icon is on the centre right"?

Comment: Yes, if you are asking about a specific card you should include a picture. However if you are asking about how to identify what set any card is from that is a different question and does not require a picture. The difference is in identifying something specific and how to identify something in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can verify your version if you look at the back of the box in the [lower right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQyex.jpg), it's the little number inside the circle. This also applies to expansions